# Prevent duplication of row in SQL Server 2008 when importing data from excel

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I am importing data from Excel into a SQL Server 2008 database and I am successful in doing that. Is there any way where I can check if the current row exist in database before inserting that particular row from Excel?

Here is the code which I am using to import data from excel

```
<pre lang="c#">
con.Open();
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string saveFolder = @"E:\"+""+path+""; //Pick a folder on your machine to store the uploaded files
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(saveFolder);
            String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + saveFolder + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Course_Data";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            excelConnection.Close();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<Script> alert('File Uploaded Successfully');</Script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<Script> alert('First select the file which you need to upload.');</Script>");
        }
con.Close();
</pre>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Bulk insert is your fastest way of getting file data into the database however you could do the bulk insert into a **temporary** table and then call a stored procedure that processes the data in that table (checks for duplicates etc) and moves it into its final destination.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL Server [INSTEAD OF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx) trigger:
make sure you use the HDR set to yes to get the header as column name in excel connection string

```
String excelConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + saveFolder + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"
```

or you will need to replace the column below by index(F$) replace $ with the index of excel column you want to compare

IE : you validate insert by course_name field

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_INS_CourseData on Course_Data
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Check for duplicate Course_name. If there is no duplicate, do an insert.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.ID
      FROM Course_Data C, inserted I
      WHERE P.Course_Name = I.Course_Name ))
   INSERT INTO Course_Data 
      SELECT *
      FROM inserted
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the data into a `DataTable` and filter out the duplicates and then insert the data into DB.

> See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23221607/311255) how to load the data from `DataReader` to `DataTable`.
>
> See [here](http://danilsafin.blogspot.in/2011/06/sql-bulk-copy-with-duplicate-keys.html) how to remove duplicates using `Comparer`