# How do I execute a SqlDataReader after sqlInsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, executenonquery

I am inserting a data row into my SQL Server database and then I want to query the data to get the unique identifier from the inserted row but my `SqlDataReader` is returning an empty dataset. I am thinking it maybe that the transaction hasn't been committed or something like that but I am not sure. I do not get an error.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO clientnames VALUES(NEWID(),'" + txtACLastName.Text + "','" + txtACFirstName.Text + "'," + 1 + ")";

    using (SqlCommand sqlInsertCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn))
    {
        intQueryResult = sqlInsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (intQueryResult == 0)
        {
            blnSuccess = false;
            goto InsertClientNamesError;
        }
        else
        {
            blnSuccess = true;
        }

        sqlInsertCmd.Dispose();
    }

    if (blnSuccess)
    {
        strQuery = "select clientID from clientnames where firstname = '" + txtACFirstName.Text + "' and lastname = '" + txtACLastName.Text + "'";

        using (SqlCommand sqlSelectCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlDataRead = sqlSelectCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlDataRead.Read())
            {
                strClientID = sqlDataRead.ToString();
            }

            sqlDataRead.Close();
            sqlSelectCmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exQuery)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("InsertClientNames: Error, " + exQuery.Message + ", has occurred.");
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the desired result because perhaps the `SqlConnection` is not opened explicitly (just a guess hard to tell without having full code). But this link shows you how to read from reader --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

But I suggest that you Please do not do it this way. Reason is you are making Two round trips to the DB Server when only one would have done the job for you **IF** you were using stored procedures. Also you are exposing yourselves to SQL Injection attacks as you are not parameterizing your queries.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.INS_clientnames 
(
   @FirstName varchar(100),
   @LastName  varchar(100),
   @NewID     int out
)
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @Err int
  set  @NewID = NewID() -- Get the New ID and store it in the variable ( @NewID ) that the SP will return back to the caller 

  INSERT INTO clientnames values (@NewID , @FirstName ,  @LastName) 
  SET @Err = @@ERROR

  IF @Error <> 0 -- Check If there was an error
  Begin 
       SET  @NewID  = -1 -- Indicates that there was an error. You could log this into a Log Table with further details like error id and name.
  END 

RETURN
END
```

C# code to execute the above stored procedure and get the NewID:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString ))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.INS_clientnames", conn))
    {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         // set up the parameters that the Stored Procedure expects
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName" , SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId"    , SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

         // set parameter values that your code will send to the SP as parameter values
         cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = txtACFirstName.Text ;
         cmd.Parameters["@LastName"].Value  = txtACLastName.Text  ;

         // open connection and execute stored procedure
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         // read output value from @NewId
         int NewID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance her, I am fairly new to c#.  Why is everyone recommending parametrized queries?  Why is concatenation so bad?

Comment: @Cass go thru this article : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp also there is plenty of material on SO about this ... just google sql injection.

Comment: #objectNotFound -- Thanks for the info.  I think I am starting to get it.  I converted my code to your example,  Thanks for all the help.  Having a forum like this is really helpful.

Comment: #objectNotFound -- Should I be doing all my SQL queries like this, even simple selects?  Do I need stored procedures for any query?

Comment: @Cass Yes. Even simple Select statements. Stored procedures offer soo much flexibility (and security and speed and power of the RDBMS engine .... ) that it really makes no sense to do it any other way (including ORM's)  . My take is that there is no substitute for proper understanding of SQL and implementing it thru Stored procedures and ADO.Net.

Comment: #objectNotFound -- How does it work for returning many columns and rows?  Do I just mark all fields as out?  Do I read it into an array in c#?

Comment: @Cass No you don't mark all fields as out. we did that in your case here because all you needed was a single integer returned after every call to the db. But DB can return rows so take a look at this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182327/SqlDataReader-Simplified the "Sales by Year" in the SQLCommand instance is a stored procedure. You can also load the output from a stored procedure into a DataTable http://stackoverflow.com/a/23221607/2628302. There are many ways you can ADO.Net to interact with DB depending on what kind of activity you are doing on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your stored procedure that inserts the record

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This will return the last identity value inserted in that table.

And use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`

`ExecuteScalar()` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. `[More info][1]`

Comment: #Antonio Avndaño Duran -- Is there a way to do this dynamically?  I am not using a stored procedure.

Comment: of course send the Query in text form, just add the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the insert sentece. ej. 'Insert into Table values (value1, value2, value3); SCOPE_IDENTITY();'

Comment: using your example ' strQuery = "INSERT INTO clientnames VALUES(NEWID(),'" + txtACLastName.Text + "','" + txtACFirstName.Text + "'," + 1 + "); SCOPE_IDENTITY();'";

Comment: This of course **only** works if the `ID` column is in fact an **identity** column. This is *often* the case - but it doesn't *have to be* (like here: the OP seems to be using a `uniqueidentifier` (=GUID) for his primary key, and that can **never** be an `identity` column, so this approach of yours will not work)

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I want by doing this -- cmd.ExecuteScalar() and "INSERT INTO clientnames VALUES(NEWID(),'" + txtACLastName.Text + "','" + txtACFirstName.Text + "'," + 1 + "); select clientid from clientnames where lastname = '" + txtACLastName.Text + "','" + txtACFirstName.Text + "'".

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches to do this:

1. either you generate the new GUID on the client side in your C# code and pass it into the query - then you *already* know what the new id is going to be, so you don't need to do a second query to get it:
2. you create your GUID on the server side and return it to the caller using the `OUTPUT` clause in your query

Approach #1:

```
// define connection string and query
string connStr = "--your connection string here--";
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Clients(ClientID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@ID, @First, @Last);";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // create the GUID in C# - this is the ID - no need to go get it again - this *IS* the id
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    // set the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Peter";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Miller";

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Approach #2:

```
// define connection string and query
string connStr = "--your connection string here--";

// query has an "OUTPUT" clause to return a newly inserted piece of data
// back to the caller, just as if a SELECT had been issued
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Clients(ClientID, FirstName, LastName) OUTPUT Inserted.ClientID VALUES(NEWID(), @First, @Last);";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // set the parameters - note: you do *NOT* send in a GUID value - the NEWID() will create one automatically, on the server
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Frank";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Brown";

    // open connection
    conn.Open();

    // execute query and get back one row, one column - the value in the "OUTPUT" clause
    object output = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    Guid newId;

    if (Guid.TryParse(output.ToString(), out newId))
    {
        //
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```