# Using IEnumerable<IDataRecord> to return data

Tags: c#, sql, string, ienumerable, reader

I am trying to return data using IEnumerable with given fields, where I am calling the the method I want to reference the data with given field name and return that.

Example, here is the function

```
    public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(string fields, string table, string where = null, int count = 0)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT @Fields FROM @Table WHERE @Where";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug)))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fields", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = where;

            cn.Open();

            using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling:

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> data = bw.GetSomeData("StaffCode, Perms", "BW_Staff", "StaffCode = 'KAA'");
```

What must I do to return the data this way or what way ?

```
string staffCode = data["StaffCode"].ToString();
string perms = data["Perms"].ToString();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: "fields" either needs to be an array of strings or a delimited string that is split on the delimiter. Then loop that array of fields to build out your cmd.Parameters.Add line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data variable is a collection of rows.  You need to iterate over the collection to do something interesting with each row.

```
foreach (var row in data)
{
    string staffCode = row["StaffCode"].ToString();
    string perms = row["Perms"].ToString();
}
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment that you only expect GetSomeData(...) to return a single row, I'd suggest 1 of two things.

Change the signature of GetSomeData to return an IDataRecord. and remove "yield" from the implementation.

```
public IDataRecord GetSomeData(string fields, string table, string where = null, int count = 0)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT @Fields FROM @Table WHERE @Where";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug)))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fields", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = where;

            cn.Open();

            using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    return (IDataRecord)rdr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
var row = data.FirstOrDefault();
if (row != null)
{
    string staffCode = row["StaffCode"].ToString();
    string perms = row["Perms"].ToString();
}
```

**Remarks:**

Your implementation of GetSomeData is incomplete.  You are not even using several of the parameters, most importantly the fields parameter.  And conceptually in SQL you can't parameterize which fields get returned or which table gets used (etc.), but rather you need to construct a dynamic query and execute it.

**Update 2**

Here is an implementation of GetSomeData that constructs a proper query (in C# 6, let me know if you need it in an earlier version).

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(IEnumerable<string> fields, string table, string where = null, int count = 0)
{
    var predicate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(where) ? "" : " WHERE " + where;
    string sql = $"SELECT { string.Join(",", fields) } FROM {table} {predicate}";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug)))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you would use it.

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> data = bw.GetSomeData(new[] { "StaffCode", "Perms" }, "BW_Staff", "StaffCode = 'KAA'");
```

You can either enumerate it or call .FirstOrDefault, it's your choice.  Each time you call GetSomeData, it will run the query.

**Update 3**

GetSomeData implemented with earlier versions of C#

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(IEnumerable<string> fields, string table, string where = null, int count = 0)
{
    var predicate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(where) ? "" : " WHERE " + where;
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} {2}", string.Join(",", fields), table, predicate);

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug)))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean it's calling the query again and again? Any way to not use a loop? thanks

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your original question.  Can you describe exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: While I can understand fields must be an array of strings, I want to call the method once so it runs one query... I enter in the field names... field1, field2, field3 as parameters.. "Select field1, field2, field3...". call the method as an array... and to output data with given field name. e.g. array["field1"], array["field2"] etc..

Comment: The code yields every row, so the receiving method get's an object which contains all the fields from the where clause. When the receiving method is finished processing a yielded row, the while(rdr.Read()) goes further and yields another row. @firstQuestion: no, the query is called once, the connection remains until all rows are yielded or calling method aborts.

Comment: I am using GetSomeData() to return only a single row which is why I didn't want to use a loop of any kind.

Comment: You are using a loop (while). Your query can return more than 1 row, but not when you 'select top 1' or field in the where clause is an unique index. 

If you only want one row, then you could put all the data in a datatable and take the first row, using index '0'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961938/populate-data-table-from-data-reader

Comment: Your update 2 is just what I am after thanks except the string sql with dollar sign is not recognizable am I using older version?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be returning any results.?

Comment: Check update 3 for a version of GetSomeData that works with earlier versions of c#.