# Loading DataTable from Excel: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to create a Datatable reading an excel file, which has a DateTime Column,rest all other columns are string. When trying to convert the DateTime column to Datetime Datatype ,I get an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'."  Could someone please guide me how do I resolve this.

```
try
        {
            string Ext = Path.GetExtension(Constants.XlFile);
            string connectionString = "";
            if (Ext == ".xls")
            {   //For Excel 97-03
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + Constants.XlFile + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            }
            else if (Ext == ".xlsx")
            {    //For Excel 07 and greater
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + Constants.XlFile + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            }
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema;
            dtSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string ExcelSheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            conn.Close();
            //Read all data of fetched Sheet to a Data Table
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + ExcelSheetName + "]";
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
            dt.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[4].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            dt.Columns[5].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[6].DataType = typeof(String);
            dt.Columns[7].DataType = typeof(String);
            //dataGrid2.Columns[4].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGrid2.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What does the date value look like coming from Excel? It must be a string format or your columns are mismatched.

Comment: Its coming as System.String. How do I change it to DateTime. I am converting it before loading fillschema

Comment: This is fine: dt.Columns[4].DataType = typeof(DateTime);. I'm assuming it's the cell or cells coming from Excel which is/are not in a format capable of converting from string to datetime. Check your Excel data. I bet there are entries in there that are invalid datetime formats.

Comment: I checked the excel but could not find any issues. How can I check which particular data has the issue.

Comment: loop through and manually add the columns instead of using a table adapter. I showed you below with documentation.

Comment: @dickrichie : Thanks Buddy, yes it was the excel..... I had to loop around to check the exact cell. Now the issue seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading into a data reader and loop through values.

```
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        foreach (DataRow drow in dtSchema.Rows)
        {
                //manually add columns here from dr
        }
```

go here for details:
[Populate data table from data reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961938/populate-data-table-from-data-reader)