# Editing data in RadGridView

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I am trying to edit a cell in a RadGridView which has a datasource set from data from an SQL view.

What I was hoping to do was to populate the grid from the view, allow edits then manually update the associated tables when a user click an "Update" button.

As soon as the user enters data into a cell and leaves the cell is presents with an error "Specified method is not supported".

I assume it's trying to update the datasource with the new value so I am trying to work out how to tell it not to.

I am populating the table with:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mydatasource))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SRID, Name, Result from EditBatchResultsView where SRID = " + drpSRID.Text, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    radGridView1.DataSource = reader;
}
```

Comment: It is better to analyze if you could provide stack trace, probably it's related to `SqlDataReader` instance because `RadGrid`'s `DataSource` property may only accept `DataTable` or `IEnumerable` sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RadGrid data binding documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/telerik-radgrid-data-binding-basics), the `DataSource` property accepts instances of the following types:

> - `DataSet`
> - `DataTable`
> - `DataView`
> - Array of `DataRow`
> - Any object collection that implements these interfaces:
>
>   - `IListSource`
>   - `IList`
>   - `IEnumerable`
>   - `ICustomTypeDescriptor`

Based from reference inspection, [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't supported because it doesn't implement those interfaces mentioned above, hence `NotSupportedException` has thrown when binding `SqlDataReader` contents into `DataSource` property directly.

As a workaround, you may create new `DataTable` instance and fill its contents from `SqlDataReader` like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mydatasource))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SRID, Name, Result from EditBatchResultsView where SRID = " + drpSRID.Text, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // fill DataTable contents
    dt.Load(reader);

    // assign DataTable as data source instead
    radGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

// DataBind goes here
```

**Note:**

The string concatenation to build SQL query may prone to SQL injection. Using parameters when passing server control value to SQL query is more recommended way:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mydatasource))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SRID, Name, Result from EditBatchResultsView where SRID = @SRID", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SRID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = drpSRID.Text;
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // fill DataTable contents
    dt.Load(reader);

    // assign DataTable as data source instead
    radGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Related issue:

[Populate data table from data reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961938/populate-data-table-from-data-reader)