# C# infinite loop when sorting GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I want to sort my GridView in the CodeBehind but my sorting methode give me an infinite loop.

My GridView, for testing, look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVEquipe" OnRowDataBound="GVEquipe_RowDataBound"  OnSorting="GridView_Sorting"    AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Employee" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Employee" DataNavigateUrlFields="Employee" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Profil.aspx?No_Emp={0}" HeaderText="No d'employé" SortExpression="Employee" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Prénom" SortExpression="FirstName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nom" SortExpression="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Machine" HeaderText="Machine" SortExpression="Machine" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Infractions" SortExpression="Alerte">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="IBAlerte" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Alerte")) >= 5d ? "~/Images/alerte3.PNG" : Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Alerte")) < 3d ? "~/Images/alerte0.PNG" : "~/Images/alerte2.PNG" %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Employee") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Événements" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="IBDelai" ImageUrl="~/Images/loupe.png" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I Generate the DataSource in the Page_Load.

My sorting method is:

```
    protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;            
        gv.Sort(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection);
    }
```

I Made it generic because I'll use it for the other GridView in the same page.

EDIT:
I change a lot of thing and now it's work.

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    sortDirection = e.SortDirection;
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    if (gv.ID == "GVEquipe")
        equipeColumnToSort = e.SortExpression;
    DataSource();
}
```

I use local variable such as:

Finally, in the end of my DataSource() method, I order my DataSource (of type IEnumerable):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(equipeColumnToSort))
{
    switch (equipeColumnToSort)
    {
        case "Employee":
            listEquipes = listEquipes.OrderBy(x => x.Employee);
            break;
        case "FirstName":
            listEquipes = listEquipes.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
            break;
        case "Name":
            listEquipes = listEquipes.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
            break;
        case "Machine":
            listEquipes = listEquipes.OrderBy(x => x.Machine);
            break;
        case "Alerte":
            listEquipes = listEquipes.OrderBy(x => x.Alerte);
            break;
    }
    if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
        listEquipes = listEquipes.Reverse();                
}
```

Comment: You're calling sort from inside sort?

Comment: rebind the grid with updated datasource depend upon the sorting direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `Sort` from inside that event, since it indeed will go in an infinite loop.

What you *should* do is handle the sorting. When you look at the sample at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will see you have to sort the data set behind your grid view.

If you have a `DataTable` for example, you should sort it something like this:

```
DataTable dt; // define your data table

dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
GVEquipe.DataSource = dt;
GVEquipe.DataBind();
```

Comment: @felix: need more help?

Comment: What is the issue with it?

Comment: I have some difficulty for setting the DataTable. I do : 
   "DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;"
And i set the session in the method for generate the DataSource like:
   "Session["TaskTable"] = GVEquipe.DataSource;"
But When The method exit the Session is lost: 
"+  base {"Impossible d'accéder à un objet supprimé.\r\nNom de l'objet : 'Accès à DataContext après Dispose.'."} System.InvalidOperationException {System.ObjectDisposedException}"

Comment: You should show your entire code. I think you can access chat now, so let's see if you can put it in there. (Eh, no you can't. Not enough rep for chat... Can you post a new question with the code?)

Comment: Sorry, you can't yet since you don't have enough rep. I would post a new question to fix that issue with your code.

Comment: Is there a way for define my DataTable from my DataSource ?

Following your link, I'm setting the Session like : 
"Session["TaskTable"] = dataSourceEquipe.Cast<object>().ToList();"
Then, I try to create a DataTable with my session:
"DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["TaskTable"];"
And I'm getting an error with the cast : "Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' en type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

Comment: You should create a `DataTable` first in your `Page_Load` like in the sample, and that one you should save in the session or so (maybe reinitialize it every time, I don't know which is best).

Comment: Would you give me an exemple for create a DataTable? Because the sample doesn't create it dynamically.

Comment: Sure, this one covers most of your question I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089514/993547. (So open a connection to your database, execute the command, and fill the datatable)

Comment: I don't use DataReader, my DataSource is set using LINQ.